# How to read assets JSON file from different package in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-test

I am working on a flutter app where I'm using multiple plugins for main app

```
main_app
-plugin1
 -example
-plugin2
 -example
-plugin3
 --example
package as well 
- <package_name>
```

every plugin have its own example folder which help me to test the UI and most of UI using common images  and icons which is kept in pure flutter package separately:

```
framework_utilities:<--(package)
   assets:
    - assets/
    - assets/images/green/2x/
    - assets/mockup/reg_state.json <--- JSON file
   lib
     src
       constant
```

and I'm able to access images and icons by passing the package reference :

```
Image.asset("assets/barcode.png", package: "framework_utilities", width: 70.0, height: pad_30),
```

now my requirement is I want to mockup whole app without including json file to main application level.

It works fine if I include json file inside the assets folder in main application but I don't want to make the copy of json file inside the plugin and application i want to keep it in a single place and read it.

I tried

```
rootBundle.loadString('assets/reg_state.json')
```

it works only individual plugin example level.

Why I need to read json file ?

If I mockup main app or individual plugin so I can provide a dummy json data to see the UI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How i resolve the issue :

import the package and plugin inside your main app `pubspec.yaml` file

```
registration_plugin:
  path: ../registration_plugin  <--- this is plugin
framework_utils:
  path: ../framework_utils      <--- this is package
```

I have json files and icons in framework_utils assets folder like :

```
assets:
  - assets/
  - assets/images/green/2x/
  - assets/reg_state.json
  - assets/user_state.json
```

Now if you want to read this file or icons in plugin I'm calling like code below :

For image

```
Image.asset("assets/user.png", package: "framework_utils", width: 70.0, height: pad_30),
```

For JSON file

```
 String path = 'packages/framework_utils/assets/user_state.json';
 String jobsString = await rootBundle.loadString(path); 
 List<dynamic> users = await jsonDecode(jobsString);
```

This is the solution for me.

Comment: Hey, what about if i want to call the assets from the package, like having a widget in the package that returns an `Image.asset` which shows an image stored in the assets folder of the package? I couldn't figure this out

Comment: the structure: ////

MyApp: lib -> my_widget.dart ////
MyPackage: 1: assets -> img_1, 2: lib -> img_widget.dart ////

class ImgWidget extends StatelessWidget { .... build(context) { return Image.asset('assets/img_1.dart'); } ////

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget { .... build(context) { return ImgWidget(); }